# CUDA correctness in presence of data dependency

Tags: for-loop, cuda, dependencies

I am working on this topic as part of my seminar presentation.I would like to know how would one write cuda programs in light of data dependency.

For example:

```
   for i=1 to N
    s1:  a[i+5]=i;         
    s2:  x[i]=a[i] + c;   //X[] is N-sized array 
   endfor
```

There is data dependency from s1 to s2.How would one write a CuDA code to vectorize this loop?say for large values of N

Answer (score 2):

The line of code s1 does not depend on s2 or anything else.  Therefore, `a[6..N-1]` can all be computed in parallel.  `a[0..5]` are unmodified by this operation.

Once the above operation is completed in parallel, another parallel operation can be performed to compute `x[i]`, since it only depends on `a[i]` which has already been computed.

This particular problem is easy to sort out into one that has no loop-carried dependencies.

Problems with loop-carried dependencies can be more difficult to sort out:

```
for i=1 to N
 a[i] += a[i-1];         
endfor
```

But such problems often fall into one or more categories of problems that have already-worked-out parallel implementations.  The above would be an example of a prefix sum.  If you do a google search on parallel prefix sum you will find [examples of how it may be handled](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) in parallel.

Another example of a loop-carried dependency is a reduction:

```
sum = 0;
for i=1 to N
 sum += a[i];         
endfor
```

The [parallel reduction cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) has an associated tutorial/whitepaper which walks through algorithm development.